# span two rows but wrap the text in one row (!)

Tags: tables, multirow

In the following table, the left most column should span two  *mini* rows. As you can see although the text is wrapped, it is fit in the first *mini* row.

I want to wrap the text so that all two *mini* rows are occupied.

How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  This is my table~\ref{t1}.

  \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{my table}
    \label{t1}
    \begin{tabular}{ |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p{2.5cm} |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p{2.2cm} 
                     |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p{1.3cm} |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p  {1.3cm}
                     |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p{1.3cm} |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p{1.3cm} 
                     |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p{1.3cm} |>{\raggedright\centering\arraybackslash} p{1.3cm} |}
        \cline{3-8}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                      & bench s1 & bench s2 & bench s3 & bench s4 & bench s5 & bench s6  \\ 
        \hline
        my\_method\_1 (degree 2)  &  coverage (\%) &   11.15  &  12.57   &  2.78    &   -17.74 &  11.52  &  8.97 \\
        \cline{2-8}
                                  &  memread (\%)  &   16.48  & 13.74    &  173.61  &   181.48 &  110.55 & 20.40  \\
        \hline
        my\_method\_2 (on miss)   &  coverage (\%) & 23.48    &  16.1    &  12.52   &   11.95  &  23.16  &  10.7  \\
        \cline{2-8}
                                  &  memread (\%)  & 44.55    &  60      &  52.91   &   55.32  &  36.58  &  52.19 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reasonable question but would be better with a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). This makes it much easier for people to play with/compile your code.

Comment: I have edited the post. Don't forget the `\usepackage{array}`

Comment: not part of an answer, but ... `-17.74` would look better with a real minus instead of a hyphen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `multirow` package and do

```
\multirow{2}{2.2cm}{my\_method\_2 (on miss)}
```

for both the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{my table}
    \label{t1}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{8}{|c}|}
        \cline{3-8}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                      & bench s1 & bench s2 & bench s3 & bench s4 & bench s5 & bench s6  \\
        \hline
       \multirow{2}{2.2cm}{\centering my\_method\_1 (degree 2)}  &  coverage (\%) &   11.15  &  12.57   &  2.78    &   -17.74 &  11.52  &  8.97 \\
        \cline{2-8}
                                  &  memread (\%)  &   16.48  & 13.74    &  173.61  &   181.48 &  110.55 & 20.40  \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{2.2cm}{\centering my\_method\_2 (on miss)}   &  coverage (\%) & 23.48    &  16.1    &  12.52   &   11.95  &  23.16  &  10.7  \\
        \cline{2-8}
                                  &  memread (\%)  & 44.55    &  60      &  52.91   &   55.32  &  36.58  &  52.19 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```